# Retain Excel Settings When Adding New CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv

I've written a python/webdriver script that scrapes a table online, dumps it into a list and then exports it to a CSV.  It does this daily.

When I open the CSV in Excel, it is unformatted, and there are fifteen (comma-delimited) columns of data in each row of column A.

Of course, I then run 'Text to Columns' and get everything in order.  It looks and works great.

But tomorrow, when I run the script and open the CSV,  I've got to reformat it.

Here is my question:   **"How can I open this CSV file with the data already spread across the columns in Excel?"**

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2013 it automatically separates the CSV into columns for me.

Comment: I'm on a mac, so I'm running 2010(maybe 2011?).   I'll swap over to 2013 on PC and see what's up.  That's great.   Thanks.

Comment: I also found this article talking about regional settings which can cause problems if you are using European regional settings http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/2293-i-have-trouble-opening-csv-files-with-microsoft-excel-is-there-a-quick-way-to-fix-this

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it as a csv file, instead of opening it directly on excel.